# Correct syntax for inputting date variable into date calculation code

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, timestamps

In my script, the following code successfully produces a timestamp variable for $n in the format  2016-04-28T15:47:48

```
for n in $(perl parsetime.pl | sed "s/.....$//")

do
echo $n
```

result is:

```
2016-04-28T15:47:48
```

However, I now want to use this variable to calculate the time 15 minutes earlier. Someone else provided me the syntax to produce the timestamp in the correct format (which worked)-this was achieved like this:

```
/opt/bin/date --date '-15 minutes 2016-04-28T15:39:27' "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%I:%S"
```

result is:

```
2016-04-28T09:09:27
```

However, my issue is now, when I try to use the $n variable instead of writing out the actual timestamp I get the message like this I get an error message.

```
for n in $(perl parsetime.pl | sed "s/.....$//")

do

/opt/bin/date --date '-15 minutes "$n"' "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%I:%S"
```

result:

```
/opt/bin/date: invalid date `-15 minutes "$n"
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I incorporate the $n variable into the code correclty?

Comment: The (nearly) free-form date entry following the `--date` switch, is only available in the GNU date. Are you sure `/opt/bin/date` is the GNU date command ?

Comment: Ah, would that explain why the -15 calc isn't calculating the correct time? (its calculating 7 hours before the said date). How would I resolve this? Sorry I'm a bit of a noobie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
'-15 minutes "$n"'
```

Single quotes stop variable substitution, so you're literally passing `"$n"` in rather than the contents of the variable.

Write:

```
/opt/bin/date --date "-15 minutes $n" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%I:%S'
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, although I now have another issue! For some reason the time calc isn't calculating 15 mins before, it's calculating 7 hours for some reason- I'm about to create a new question.